# Logging in Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, logging, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch. I want to know how we can put logging statement while implementing spring batch readers and writers. For example if I define readers and writers in spring context XML then later on I can't debug where my code failed.
How can I achieve logging in Spring batch.
Do I need to extend the available reader classes in java for example flatFileReader and put logging statement in java class.

Or can I achieve this while maintaining my code in context file?

And in case I want to throw my user defined exceptions then how can I do this.

Comment: What, exactly, are you looking to debug?  Spring Batch has quite a bit of debug logging in it's existing components which can be turned on by configuring the log level.

Comment: I don't understand the question in fact.  If you want to log in your own implemented reader, just do logging as in any place (assuming you are using SLF4J or similar logger), just get a logger and log with it.  For throwing exception, just throw it.  Signature of `read()` in `ItemReader` allows throwing any exception...  I am confused in your question

Comment: Hi Michael - could you pleas suggest me a good article for that

Comment: Hi Adrian - In case I dont want to implement the existing readers, And I do my code in context xml. how can I capture the spring logs in my application. Please suggest

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you want to debug, if you looking for debugging the out-of-the-box readers and writers, set up your log4j level to debug for the spring batch package.

```
###  debug your specific package or classes with the following example
#log4j.logger.org.springframework.jdbc=debug
#log4j.logger.org.springframework.batch=debug
```

Most of the out-of-box readers and writers should have sufficient debugging.

Comment: More detail needed. This does not work when added top application.properties of a basic project (Spring batch 4.3)

Answer (score 1):

There is an advanced listener architecture at Spring Batch API. You can use listener classes/interfaces to manage your logging such as `ItemListenerSupport`, `ItemReadListener`, `ItemProcessListener` or `ItemWriteListener`. 
Just implement/extend the class/interfaces that you need and customize the listener methods with overriding according to your needs.

For logging exceptions, please [refer to this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/common-patterns.html#loggingItemProcessingAndFailures).

Answer (score 0):

Use Slf4j for logging, using sl4j you could log anything inside your batch job

```
 log.info("Converting (" + jobDetails + ") into (" + transformedJobDetails + ")");
```