# Is there any way to debug spring batch in eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-batch-admin

I am new to spring batch and many time I face issue while coding.So is there any way to debug spring batch in eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about which level of debug you will need but you can take a look into this posts:

[Logging in Spring batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644562/logging-in-spring-batch)

https://keyholesoftware.com/2012/06/25/getting-started-with-spring-batch-part-two/

Also you can try using the Spring Eclipse IDE:
https://spring.io/tools/eclipse

Comment: I just need to debug the batch application just like a normal spring MVC Java web application.